# Add counter column to table for every n rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel

I am looking to add a column like `CusID` that would be essentially a counter that can be chosen according to variable `@nrows`. In this case `@nrows` is 3 and just simply goes down the table date added and for each item in the row it adds the counter.

```
CustID --- DateAdded ---

 1         2012-02-09 
 1         2012-02-09 
 1         2012-02-08 
 2         2012-02-07 
 2         2012-02-07
 2         2012-02-07 
 3         2012-02-06
 3         2012-02-06
```

If someone could tell me how to do that in MSSQL, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to add a column that will increment. So you want a function that takes in an integer and returns a column that numerically goes through and assigns each row a number according to that param?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need it to do.

Comment: Mark and I both have answers below that meet this criteria, is there a reason either one of these does not work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I actually Meant MSSQL and not EXCEL.

Comment: Minus one on the question, for failing the MSSQL and EXCEL clarification.  Maybe you should read How to Ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask    Then you might want also to change the tags on your question so it will show up as a MSSQL question and not as an EXCEL

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Excel with two formulas the first one counts rows and compares to @nrows

Location A3 in screen shot

```
=IF(B3=B2,(A2+1),1)
```

Second places the ID, location B4 in the screen shot

```
=IF(A3=$B$1,B3+1,B3)
```

The value in B1 is the variable "@nrows"

The value in B3 is the starter ID, so you can start at any value you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about
    =MAX(1,ROUNDUP(ROW()/@NROWS,0))
which I believe produces the result you want.

One reason it might not work is the "@NROWS" variable, which OP indicated he wanted to use. I confess that in my testing I used
    =MAX(1,ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0))

Comment: This answer needs a bit more something, I played around with it and did not get it working.

Comment: That works; If I put =MAX(1,ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/3,0)) in cell A2, and paste it down it counts as requested with increments by what ever value replaces the "3".

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to do it in excel, but you can first load data into SQL server, then the following syntax will help you

```
select NTILE(@NRows) over (order by DateAdded desc), DateAdded from tablename
```

Comment: This only divides it into (@NRows) groups and not divide by @NRows.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to the row set. It will produce sequential numbers starting from 1. Modify those by adding `@nrows - 1` to them and dividing the results by `@nrows`:

```
SELECT
  CustID = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateAdded) + @nrows - 1) / @nrows,
  DateAdded
FROM atable
;
```

See a demo [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e3f3/4).